Curve-fitting audio decay harmonics
I'm examining the frequencies produced by pressing middle C on a piano.
I've used Fourier analysis to extract the amplitude of the middle C frequency per window of time,
as well as the integer multiples (harmonics) of that frequency.
To simplify, i'm only mapping the curve after the 'attack', so it'll only be downhill.
I'm hoping to 'curve-fit' this somehow so i can roughly synthesize the same sound.
Initially i thought a parabola looks nice, however it will eventually start curving up again which is
likely a strong indicator it's the incorrect fit.
This ribbon chart is an indication of my results. The time of the peak of the sound is at left, with time extending right. Amplitude is on the Y axis, and each ribbon is a harmonic aka multiple of the middle-c frequency. The ribbon 'furthest away' from the camera is the fundamental frequency.
What fitting equation would you recommend? Some form of decay? The simpler the better.
Any advice appreciated thankyou.


Re "only be downhill:" yes, on average, as energy is dissipated; but I believe the dynamics are more complex than that, because energy can be exchanged between modes over time (and between modes of the string and modes of the piano's superstructure), possibly causing some modes to increase in amplitude briefly before ultimately decaying.  An excellent approach would be to inform your choice of model by means of a physical analysis of the system.

A little Googling turns up a paper that answers your question in detail.  T. Cheng, S. Dixon and M. Mauch, "Modelling the decay of piano sounds," 2015 IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP), South Brisbane, QLD, Australia, 2015, pp. 594-598, doi: 10.1109/ICASSP.2015.7178038.  It is freely available on the Web.
